# Disable Header for specific Scene in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

If you can't figure out my question by the title then I will give a small example:

So I have "landing page" where users either login or register, pending success, the user would then be re-routed to the "main" page of the app. On this main page though I would rather not have the default header that is used in react-native-router-flux and replace it with a more sleek react-native-scrollable-view for presentational purposes.

Is there a prop that I can set to false for this to be achieved or am I asking to much of react-native-router-flux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

Never mind...

`<Scene key="main" component={Main} hideNavBar={true} />`

does the trick

Comment: In my test, this does not work as of `"react-native-router-flux": "3.43.0"` unless I'm doing it wrong. That flag disabled the headers for all the sibling scenes as well.

Comment: I have tabs scene like this: <Scene key="tabbar" tabs tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}} hideNavBar >  ... </Scene>.   It seems this hideNavBar attribute won't working with tabs. Any thoughts?